# Connect-N Game in Python needs Winner function

Tags: python

**Python Code** Connect-N Game.

Hi there, I need help with detecting the winner for the 8 directions in Connect N. The game is like Connect 4, but the user inputs N to whatever they want it to be. So could be Connect 5, or 6, etc. However, at the moment, my code is not detecting the 8 directions. I really am struggling with this function. Can someone show me how some code that would work to apply into my def *have_winner* function.

Thank you!
[Instructions for the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ctbe6.jpg)

```
# GLOBAL VARIABLES
N = 5
num_row = N + 3
num_col = N + 2
disk = ['\u2B1C', '\u26AA', '\u26AB']
board = []

def init_board(n):
    '''initialise the board'''
    global N, num_row, num_col
    N = n
    num_row = n + 3
    num_col = n + 2
    for c in range(num_col):
        board.append([0]*num_row)
    
def display():
    '''print the board'''
    to_print = "    "
    for i in range(num_col):
        to_print = to_print + f'[{i}]'
    print(to_print)
    for i in range(num_row):
        to_print = f'[{i:2}]'
        for j in range(num_col):
            to_print = f'{to_print}{disk[board[j][i]]:2}'
        print(to_print)

def game():
    '''play the game'''
    n = input('Please input N:')
    init_board(int(n))
    
    p = 0
    while True:
        c = input(f'Player {p} select colomn:')
        if c == 'q': # quit the game
            print(f'Player {p} resigned')
            break
            
        # drop disk    
        f = drop_disk(int(c), p+1)
        if f == 0: # illegal move
            print(f'Column {c} is an illegal move')
            continue            
        display()
        
        # check winner and switch side
        w = have_winner()
        if w == 1:
            print(f'Player {p} won')
            break
        elif w == 2:
            print('draw')
            break
        else:
            p = (p + 1)%2

def drop_disk(c, player):
    """player drop a disk at ch colomn. Return 1 if successfully drop the disk, return 0 if this is a illegal move, e.g. the colomn is full."""
    if board[c][0] != 0:
        return 0
    for r in range(num_row -1, -1, -1):
        if board[c][r] == 0:
            board[c][r] = player
            return 1
    return 0

def have_winner():
    """return 1 if there is a winner, return 2 if the board is full, return 0 otherwise"""
    for c in range(num_col):
        for r in range(num_row):
            if board[c][r] == 0:
                return 0
    return 2
# MAIN CODE
game()
```

Comment: You need to check if there is a vertical/horizontal line of length N. Start iterating from (0,0) coordinate on the board, check vertically if (0,0) has the same color as (N,0), if so it's a candidate, check that all squares between (0,0) and (N,0) are the same. Similarly, check if endpoint (0,0) and (0,N) are the same. If so, check that all squares between (0,0) and (0,N) are the same. Now you've done checking square (0,0)

Comment: Move to square (0,1), repeat the same check against (N,1) and against (0,N+1). You've done checking the square (0,1). Do the same checks for all squares, note that you only need check up to column number 2, because the board has only N+2 columns. And you need to check up to row number 3, because the board has only N+3 rows